# charCodeAt is not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, char

How can this be possible:

```
var string1 = "", string2 = "";

//comparing the charCode
console.log(string1.charCodeAt(0) === string2.charCodeAt(0)); //true

//comparing the character
console.log(string1 === string2.substring(0,1));              //false

//This is giving me a headache.
```

<sub>http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/B9Xdk/</sub>

If their char codes are the same in both strings, by comparing the character itself should return `true`. It is true when I put in `a` and `ab`. But when I put in these strings, it simply breaks.

Some said that it might be the encoding that is causing the problem. But since it works perfectly fine when there's only one character in the string literal, I assume encoding has nothing to do with it.

<sub>(This question addresses the core problem in my previous questions. Don't worry I deleted them already.)</sub>

Comment: `string2.substring(0,1)` actually yields an empty string

Comment: @baldrs - [I checked](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/BLGYu/), it's not empty. It just has zero width.

Comment: `''.length` yields `4` :)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 it's a problem with multibyte encoding, where `` is two characters

Comment: Note that if you change the `substring` call to `string2.substring(0,2)` your last statement outputs `true`.

Comment: @baldrs - Oh my gosh you just solved my problem it works now. I have absolutely no idea `` is two characters...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JavaScript, strings are treated by characters instead of bytes, but only if they can be expressed in 16-bit code points.

A majority of the characters will cause no issues, but in this case they don't "fit" and so they occupy 2 characters as far as JavaScript is concerned.

In this case you need to do:

```
string2.substring(0, 2) // ""
```

For more information on Unicode quirkiness, see [UTF-8 Everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/).

Comment: @halex I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @halex Yes, which is what my answer mentions.

Comment: But why do you add the comment `// ""`?

Comment: Because that's what the result of `string2.substring(0, 2)` is.

Comment: For me it's the swirling thing and not the arrow thing.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan What 300? Am I not seeing something? :)

Comment: @Jack yeeee you nailed it now!

Comment: @Jack Yes that's what I mean :) +1 btw

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I seriously couldn't tell the difference lol .. the code points are now `0xd83c 0xdf00` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method to compare 2 strings:

```
string1.localeCompare(string2);
```

Comment: This method is widely unsupported, unfortunately, if the code is going to be executed in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Substring parameters are the index where he starts, and the end, where as if you change it to substr, the parameters are index where to start and how many characters.